# How to calculate right directional vector from delta roll?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math, rotational-matrices

Given a variable _roll and the current right directional vector, how would one calculate the new right vector when rotating an object (in this case a camera)?

```
// Calculate right.  Rotate right vector by yaw.
glm::vec3 right = glm::vec3(glm::eulerAngleY(_yaw) * glm::vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 
0.0f, 1.0f));

// Rotate right vector by roll
right = glm::vec3(glm::eulerAngleZ(_roll) * glm::vec4(right, 1.0f));

// Normalize right
right = glm::normalize(right);
```

Above is my current thinking, yaw is working fine, however roll seems to be producing peculiar results. Am I missing something?

Edit: After some Experimentation I have also discovered that:

- Rolling works only when looking directly up or down the Z axis.
- Whilst rolled over, using the preexisting *pitch* method to pitch up, I pitch to *global* up rather than *the cameras* own up.

Comment: Rotations are made around one axis (let's call *global axis*). Every *local axis* of the object must be rotated around that *global axis*.

Comment: Okay so you're definitely onto something here, but could you explain it to me a bit more? I'm updating the question with what I've found out after some experimentation.